# How can I randomly instantiate a prefab in a fixed array of colliders in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity game and would like to spawn the end goal (a prefab with some meshes ad collision box) randomly from a selection of 3 or 4 possible locations across the map.

I know I need to use an array of some sort, and make it so the prefabs don't intersect with other assets. I just can't visualize the solution.

Can anybody suggest how to at least get started?

Comment: Your problem is not well defined, but at least post any effort that you have done yet?
For example, you can use a list of Transform objects and choose randomly from them, all these objects positions are defined before the level is created

Answer (score 0):

1) In the unity editor, create empty game objects in the locations where you want the goal to spawn.

2) In code, in your game logic monobehavior in charge of spawning the end goal, declare a public array of GameObjects

3) Using the inspector, add the empty GameObjects to the array in your gamelogic monobehavior

4) In code, randomly spawn the goal and "attach" it to the world using code like:

```
var rand = new Random();
i = rand.next(myGoalPositions.Length);
var goal = Object.Instantiate(myEndGoalPrefab, myGoalPositions[i], false );
```

To get them to not intesect with anything... the easiest way is to build your world so they won't intersect with anything.